# Need Regex code, 6 character alphanumeric

Tags: regex, informatica, enterprise

I am creating a custom Data Domain using Informatica Enterprise Data Catalog and I need a regex code for a 6 character alphanumeric code where the first 3 characters are letters and the last 3 characters are alphanumeric.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}$
```

Comment: Use `{3}` instead of `{3,}`

Comment: `{3,}` means "at least 3". You want *exactly* 3, which is `{3}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thanks all for your input. The expression is working correctly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments to your question, `{3,}` will match the preceding block at least 3 times. `{x,y}` means at least x and at most y. If you want to match exactly 3 times, you should use `{3}`.

You can always test your expressions on http://regex101.com.

Comment: Thank you Tomas, the link to test my expression was very helpful